# Como gerar tokens seguros de forma dinâmica

Tags: autenticação, token

Aplicações diversas usam autenticação via token para manter uma comunicação na rede de forma segura. Só que, usando tokens gerados dinamicamente, a probabilidade de quebra do mesmo diminui bastante. Então aí que entra a dúvida: Como gerar tokens dinâmicos de maneira segura? Quais parâmetros usar ou não usar? Existem boas práticas? Quais?

Comment: A maioria das aplicações como Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc utilizam o padrão OAuth / OAuth 2.0 para a realização da autenticação via token segue alguns links para estudo sobre o padrão espero ter ajudado: [Wikipédia OAuth (PT-BR)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) [Best practices around generating OAuth tokens? (Dúvida semelhante StackOverflow - ENG)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626575/best-practices-around-generating-oauth-tokens) [OAuth Core 1.0 Revision A (Documentação padrão OAuth 1.0 - ENG)](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#rfc.section.6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe o padrão [**JSON Web Token (JWT)**](https://jwt.io/) - [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) - que define um modo compacto e independente para transmitir informação em segurança entre duas partes no formato JSON.

Estes dados podem ser verificados quanto à autenticidade porque são assinados digitalmente. É possível assinar utilizando uma senha (com o algoritmo HMAC) ou um par de chaves público/privada usando RSA.

#### Estrutura

Exemplo de token JWT:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzODY4OTkxMzEsImlzcyI6ImppcmE6MTU0ODk1OTUiLCJxc2giOiI4MDYzZmY0Y2ExZTQxZGY3YmM5MGM4YWI2ZDBmNjIwN2Q0OTFjZjZkYWQ3YzY2ZWE3OTdiNDYxNGI3MTkyMmU5IiwiaWF0IjoxMzg2ODk4OTUxfQ.uKqU9dTB6gKwG6jQCuXYAiMNdfNRw98Hw_IWuA5Ma
```

São três partes separadas por `.`, codificadas por base64 individualmente:

```
<base64-encoded header>.<base64-encoded claims>.<base64-encoded assinatura>
```

É importante observar que JWT não encripta o payload, apenas o assina. Portanto não se deve enviar informações confidenciais por JWT. Apenas informações que devem ser verificadas/confiadas.

#### Como funciona?

Logo após fazer login com sucesso, o servidor retorna o token JWT gerado para o cliente, que deve enviá-lo em todas as requisições subsequentes no header, conforme segue:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

O servidor recebe, valida o token e utiliza a informação oriunda deste para definir se o usuário pode acessar a aplicação ou as rotas protegidas. Assim, este mecanismo de autenticação caracteriza-se como *stateless*, sendo uma ótima opção para escalar a aplicação em diversos servidores.

#### Qual parâmetro utilizar?

Isso depende de cada aplicação. Entretanto, uma prática bastante [comum](https://jhipster.github.io/security/) é utilizar apenas o login do usuário e suas *ROLES* como base para geração do token. Assim, é possível determinar através do próprio token se o usuário pode acessar tal rota, sem nem mesmo acessar o banco de dados.

#### Geração do token

Uma boa prática aqui é o uso de tempo de expiração e ROLES (*Authority*).

```
String secretKey = 35725c901c45f1c13f9e3fe8421a15dd26130118; // Chave privada de exemplo
String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("auth", authentication.getAuthority())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .compact();
```

#### Validação do token

```
public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
        return true;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Leitura dos dados do token

```
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(secretKey)
        .parseClaimsJws(token)
        .getBody();
```

A partir do objeto `Claims` pode obter a ROLE salva com `claims.get("auth").toString()`.

#### Linguagens

Apesar de adicionar exemplos em Java, o JWT está disponível na maioria das linguagens de programação: .NET, Python, Node.js, Java, PHP, Ruby, Go, JavaScript, and Haskell.